# How to resize the image on label widget

Tags: image, resize, tcl, tk-toolkit

Currently, I use `label` widget with the `-image` option to display a image on the TK GUI as following :

```
image create photo plot1 -file new.gif
label .la1 -image plot1 -background white
```

It works well. But now I want to make the image resize as the user drags the GUI.

For other tk widget, The `columnconfigure` and `rowconfigure` can realize the resize function. But how to do this for image on label?

Comment: See [this wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8448).

Comment: When you know how to resize the image, you will need to bind the configuration of the window to the size of the image. For example, `bind .w configure {resize_image %h %w}` where `resize_image` will be your own proc to update the image with the updated image provided the new dimensions of the window.

Comment: I check the wiki and the Tk manual. And it seems that the image resize can only support integer multiple sizing. Since the -zoom and -sumsample option only allow integer parameter.

Comment: Check out the proc `image%` on the wiki. This proc accepts stuff like 130 (for an increase of 30%). You could perhaps do 5% increases, or 10% increases that way.

Comment: It's really difficult to do this well. In particular, you'll need to use some C code (maybe in an existing extension) to get performant resizing.

Comment: You could include several different sizes of images with your product and switch the displayed image for the label depending on the size.